# Should I do a URL fetch or call the class method ? Which would be the best option

Tags: python, google-app-engine, webapp2

Which would be a better to way to get contents from two different request handlers? 
This is how my app structure looks like

```
#/twitter/<query>
class TwitterSearch(webapp2.RequestHandler):

    def get(self,query):

        #get data from Twitter
        json_data = data_from_twiiter()
        return json_data

#/google/<query>
class GoogleSearch(webapp2.RequestHandler):

    def get(self,query):

        #get data from Twitter
        json_data = data_from_google()
        return json_data
```

Now I can access twitter search data and Google search data separately by calling their respective URL.

I also need to combine both these search results and offer to the user. What would be my best approach to do this ?

Should I call the get method of the respective classes like this ?

```
#/search/<query> 
#Combined search result from google and twitter
class Search(webapp2.RequestHandler):

    def get(self,query):

        t = TwitterSearch()
        twitterSearch = t.get(self,query)

        g = GoogleSearch()
        googlesearch = g.get(self,query)
```

Or fetch the data from URL using urllib or something like this ?

```
#/search/<query> 
#Combined search result from google and twitter
class Search(webapp2.RequestHandler):

    def get(self,query):

        t = get_data_from_URL('/twitter/'+query)

        g = get_data_from_URL('/google/'+query)
```

Or is there some other way to handle this situation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shouldn't make HTTP calls to your own application, that introduces a completely unnecessary level of overhead.

I would do this by extracting the query code into a separate function and calling it from both request handlers.

Comment: Thanks. That's exactly what I just did.